# Correct way to fetch through array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

In the below compoenent, the function is neverending. Can someone tell me what to fix so that in the end the beers array in the state has 5 names?

```
export default class GetBeers extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          beers: [],
          didError: false
        };
      this.getBeerInfo = this.getBeerInfo.bind(this);
    }
    
    render() {
      return (
        ...
    }
    getBeerInfo() {
        let beerArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
        this.props.beerArr.map(id => {
          fetch(`https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/${id}`)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(json => {
            this.setState(state => {
              const beers = state.beers.concat(json[0].name);
         
              return {
                beers
              };
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            this.setState({
              didError : true
            });
          });
        })
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your code should be somethings like this ..

```
import React from 'react';
export default class GetBeers extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            beers: [],
            didError: false
        };
        this.getBeerInfo = this.getBeerInfo.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.state.beers}</div>
        )
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getBeerInfo()
    }

    getBeerInfo() {
        let beerArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
        beerArr.map(id => {
            fetch(`https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/${id}`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(json => {
                    this.setState({
                        //const beers = state.beers.concat(json[0].name);
                        //return {
                            //beers
                        //};
                        beers: this.state.beers.concat(json[0].name)
                    });
                    console.log('well at least this works')
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    this.setState({
                        didError : true
                    });
                });
        })
    }
}
```

It is advised that you use the componentDidMount() lifecycle method for the fetch api and add what @atahnksy said.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using setState, you can try this:

```
this.setState({ beers: [...this.state.beers, json[0].name])
```

This might fix your problem.

Comment: It is still neverending, unfortunately.

Comment: It re-renders everytime `state` updates. So this one won't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the `render` method using a combination of ternary operator(to display appropriate message when it cannot reach the server), format with map and ordered list to get something like this :

```
render() {
    return (
        <div><ol>{this.state.beers.length!==0 ? this.state.beers.map((beer)=><li>{beer}</li>) :"Could not retrieve any bears. Try again/ensure you can access the server/networtk"}</ol></div>
    )
}
```